# EC2 - Remove EC2 from VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I was wondering if it's possible to remove an ec2 instance from VPC. If so, how can i do it? I was doing some tests and and i would like to remove my instances without terminate all of them.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot move an instance between VPC and non-VPC, only launch new instances.

The 'opposite' of VPC is called **EC2 Classic**. As you can tell by the name, Amazon is depreciating this mode. All new accounts since December 2013 are VPC only. Several new features only work in VPC (for example, 'Enhanced Networking').

The writing is on the wall: You will need to move to VPC sooner or later.  During the migration, you can use EC2 ClassicLink to let your EC2 Classic boxes talk with boxes in your VPC groups.

Answer (score 3):

Remeber that when you create an instance, you specify the VPC that it will be launched in. It is not possible to change the VPC without terminating the instance and re-launching it in the new one.

One possible option would be to create an AMI of your currently running instance, and relaunch it in your preferred VPC using that AMI.

Comment: But if you create a vpc, all stances are attached to vpc

Comment: You can't create new non-VPC instances now as EC2 Classic is deprecated. If you don't launch in your custom VPC it will launch in the default VPC.